# Simplify the expression: $\sin x (1+\cot^2 x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Simplify the expression: $\sin x (1+\cot^2 x)$

Please help. I have tried all identities and still can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: cosec x. What's wrong with your attempt ?

Comment: I recommend you for next time to include all the work you've done so far so that we don't repeat what you already know.

Comment: Do you mean $(\sin x)(1+\cot^2x)$ or $\sin(x(1+\cot^2x))$?

Answer (score 3):

Note the following identity:
$$\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}\equiv 1$$
If you divide both sides by $\sin^2{x}$, you can derive another identity:
$$1+\cot^2{x}\equiv \csc^2{x}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: yes i got there originally but got stuck at sinx x 1/sin^2 x

Comment: thats where i got that i showed you im just not sure how to multiply with the sin and the sin^2

Comment: Maybe you don't know this? $$\sin^2{x}\equiv (\sin{x})^2$$ Dividing the numerator and denominator of the fraction by $\sin{x}$, you obtain: $$\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin^2{x}}=\frac{1}{\sin{x}}$$

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean the expression

$\sin{x} \left(1 + \cot^2{x} \right)  = \sin{x} \left(1 + \frac{1}{\tan^2{x}} \right)  = \sin{x} \left(1 + \frac{\cos^2{x}}{\sin^2{x}} \right)  = \sin{x} + \frac{\cos^2{x}}{\sin{x}} = \sin{x} + \cos{x}\cot{x}$.

However, it's not becoming much simpler. There are many forms that you can give for this expression. Ask Wolfram Alpha for more expressions. According to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=csc%28x%29&lk=1&rawformassumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Math%22%7D), it can also be $\csc(x)$.

Comment: do you know how you get to csc(x)?

Comment: $\sin{x} \left(1 + \cot^2{x} \right)=\sin x \csc^2 x=\frac{\sin x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{1}{\sin x}=\csc x$